# Pause a video with firstChild?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Super new to Javascript, and I'm having trouble finding any solutions to this anywhere. I'm not sure if the issue is with firstChild, or with .pause()

The "tabcontent[i].firstChild.pause()" line breaks the entire function...

Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yr97xz07/) with the effected code, but no image/videos because they are still local.

And here's the effected code here:

HTML:

```
<div class="video-portfolio">
        <div class="video-nav-contain">
            <ul class="video-nav">
                <li id="hide1">
                    <a href="#" class="tablinks" onclick="openVideo(event, 'garageBar')">
                        <img class="tab-icon" src="images/garage-bar-tab.png" onClick="videoDisplay1">
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li id="hide2">
                    <a href="#" class="tablinks" onclick="openVideo(event, 'murryLake')">
                        <img class="tab-icon" src="images/murry-lake-tab.png">
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li id="hide3">
                    <a href="#" class="tablinks" onclick="openVideo(event, 'roofFun')">
                        <img class="tab-icon" src="images/roof-fun-tab.png">
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="garageBar" class="tabcontent" id="videoName">
            <video class="vid-tabs" controls>
                <source src="images/garage%20bar.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
        </div>
        <div id="murryLake" class="tabcontent">
            <video class="vid-tabs" controls>
                <source src="images/murry%20lake2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
        </div>
        <div id="roofFun" class="tabcontent">
            <video class="vid-tabs" controls>
                <source src="images/rooftop%20fun.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And then the Javascript:

```
function openVideo(evt, videoName) {
var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    tabcontent[i].firstChild.pause()
}
tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
}
document.getElementById(videoName).style.display = "block";
evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not with `pause()` but with `firstChild`. the video element is coming to be the second child. `firstChild` gives the output as `#text`

Use `childNodes[1]` to access the second child i.e the video

```
tabcontent[i].childNodes[1].pause();
```

JS

```
 <script>
    function openVideo(evt, videoName) {
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
        console.log(tabcontent[i].childNodes[1]);
    tabcontent[i].childNodes[1].pause();
    }
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    document.getElementById(videoName).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
    </script>
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/mayank_shubham/yr97xz07/2/)